# Displaying text input from the rendered keyboard in android

Tags: android

I am rendering keyboard into my application. I want user to enter the character from the keyboard i rendered and I want to display that text onto screen character by character as user enters. How do I achieve this?

Comment: please post what you have tried

Comment: what did you use for keyboard rendering ? please, post relevant code

Comment: Its very big code to post here. point is that I can detect what key has pressed, now I want to use some text box or something similar to display it.